# how to rearrange sqlite results

Tags: sql, python-3.x, sqlite

hey guys so i have these 2 lists being pulled out of sqlite3

```
    connection      = sqlite3.connect('intel.db')
    database        = connection.cursor()
    top             = database.execute("SELECT logtext from logs order by length(logtext) desc limit 10").fetchall()
    usr             = database.execute("SELECT loguser from logs order by length(logtext) desc limit 10").fetchall()

    print(usr,top)
```

> ('DIRECT_TEST',), ('ROBOT',), ('ZERO',), ('TEST',), ('Yan Yan',),
>   ('Toasty',), ('!☆♡Fox Wizard♡☆',), ('Agibear',), ('ZEROBIT',), ('Big
>   Bad Bug',)] [('30000',), ('1605',), ('715',), ('333',), ('209',) 
>   ('260',), ('128',), ('376',), ('86',), ('0',)]

how can i make them print like this :

[image]

> Tiny update.. I changed the logtext from TEXT to INT sorting got
>   solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 for row in database.execute("SELECT logtext, loguser from logs"):
    print(row)
```

Your output is not ordered, so not sure why you need that

But if you did...

```
 SELECT logtext, cast(loguser as INTEGER) loguser from logs ORDER BY loguser DESC
```

Comment: Why.. didn't i think of this ! I'm such a noob 
Direct and straight to the point!
Thank you so much !
cant flag it right answer yet need 8 more mins

Comment: No problem. Just remember that you can test sqlite queries outside of Python

Comment: 1 more question please..
the reason why im ordering them is so they come in highest number first..

Anyway to achieve that ?

Comment: Add the ORDER BY back to it

Comment: by the way.. ordering still isn't working properly and I'm clueless why this is what im using...

for row in database.execute("SELECT loguser, logtext from logs order by length(logtext) desc"):

Comment: Hint: What is `length()` actually doing? If you want to order by the actual number value, don't get the length of the string, get the actual numeric value

Comment: im sorry its 6am.. i have no clue how to sort them by number i'd think of using count(logtext) but i doubt that'll do anything

Comment: You can `select logtext, length(logtext)` to see what's happening

Comment: Tiny update.. I changed the logtext from TEXT to INT sorting got solved.